# How to write a while loop\if statement with assembly language in C program?

Tags: c, if-statement, assembly, while-loop, inline-assembly

I am trying to write a program to read a sentence and count the number of uppercase letters.

Specifically I am trying to convert the c code shown below into assembly language:

```
scanf("%c", &L );
while(L !='\n')
 {
  if(L>='A' && L<='Z')
    V++;
  scanf("%c", &L);
}
```

Here is my code for assembly :

```
  _asm
    {
    call read
    mov V, 0;
    while:  cmp L, '\n'
    je  exit,loop
    cmp L, 'A'
    jl cont
    cmp L, 'Z'
    jg cont
    inc V
    cont: call read
      jmp while
      exit: jmp
}
```

However this code does not run successfully as I keep getting an error message stating :**Warning C4405: 'loop' : identifier is reserved word**. Sorry for any coding mistakes,I am new to assembly language. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: x86 instruction set contains `loop` and I think the message says that the identifier is confusing to the ibstructuon. Moreover, x86 `je` instruction will take one operand, not two.

Comment: Also, there won't be `jmp` instruction with no operand in x86. Where to jump?

Comment: `do{ stuff } while(condition)` loops translate into asm more easily (because the condition is already at the bottom, so you don't have to duplicate it ahead of the loop).  So if your algo doesn't need a test before the first iteration, think of it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code you're getting is relatively straightforward; you're using the identifier 'loop' as an (extraneous) operand for your je (jump on equality). Your final unconditional jump also needs an operand of some type.

```
 _asm
    {
    call read
    mov V, 0;
    while:  cmp L, '\n'
    je  exit
    cmp L, 'A'
    jl cont
    cmp L, 'Z'
    jg cont
    inc V
    cont: call read
      jmp while
      exit: jmp somewhere
}
```

The identifier 'loop' is used in x86 assembly, so is barred from use as a label. It appears that it was included here by accident, though, as there is no such label defined and the loop appears complete without it.